# MySQL: IP Address JOIN + ORDER DESC kills performance

Tags: mysql

My goal is simple: JOIN by IP addresses from different logs; at the client-side I'm trying to determine where JavaScript errors are being spawned from (e.g. humans or bots) which I am inferring from if a isset($row[date_xy]) via PHP.

This query does work fine without ORDER BY, once I throw that in to the mix MySQL jumps to 30% CPU utilization and stays there for a few seconds before I kill the process. I'm testing this locally of course. I want to use *ORDER BY je.date DESC* as I'm not interested in the oldest possible entries.

I have tried sub-selects, it's been a while since I've done anything fancier than a basic JOIN. It's important that I keep the syntax SOL-neutral.

```
SELECT 
je.date AS date_js, 
lb.date AS date_lb, 
lh.date AS date_lh 

FROM log_javascript_errors AS je 

LEFT JOIN log_bots AS lb ON je.ip = lb.ip 

LEFT JOIN log_humans AS lh ON je.ip = lh.ip 

ORDER BY je.date DESC 

LIMIT 20, 20
```

Comment: ORDER BY is just for ordering your result set. Noting to do with data. What is datatype of je.date?

Comment: Do you have an index on `je(date)` ?

Comment: Add the tables' definitions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and the execution plan of the query (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone a different route as I must admit this the design of the tables did not consider this possibility when I created them originally; we've all encountered this. I did learn SQL vendor-neutral CASE syntax however though found out I did not even need to use that after some modifications so I'm up-voting the two replies I received as thanks for expanding my understanding of SQL. For those who find this question directly relevant to their goals I ended up adding a "type" column which I am using the server scripting language to fill in the rest in order to generate what I need to see in my logs. I think if I redesigned it from scratch I would have created a master sessions table for all "types" (humans, search engines and rejects) and then possibly try a double LEFT JOIN though I'm not sure how well that would work offhand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add indexes for log_javascript_errors.date to speed ordering up.
And indexes for log_bots.ip, log_humans.ip, log_javascript_errors.ip to make joins faster.

UPDATE

```
CREATE INDEX je_date ON log_javascript_errors (date);
CREATE INDEX je_ip ON log_javascript_errors (ip);
CREATE INDEX lb_ip ON log_bots (ip);
CREATE INDEX lh_ip ON log_humans (ip);
```

Comment: Could you please further clarify about indexes?

Comment: Thanks, tried it out and didn't see any improvement. Does the index name (e.g. je_ip) need to directly correlate to the SELECT query or is it simply for reference only?

Comment: @John Nope, feel free choosing index names. I made one correction. Check please.

Comment: @Maksym: Mysql ignores the `DESC` in index creation.

Comment: It's not bad to have it (if you plan to migrate to another DBMS) or just in case MySQL supports it in the future.

Comment: My approach ended up being different, +1 though, see my answer below for more details, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After adding appropriate indexes, and if your query is still slow, you can try this variation:

```
SELECT 
je.date AS date_js, 
lb.date AS date_lb, 
lh.date AS date_lh 

FROM 
    ( SELECT ip, date 
      FROM log_javascript_errors 
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 40
    ) AS je 

LEFT JOIN log_bots AS lb ON je.ip = lb.ip 

LEFT JOIN log_humans AS lh ON je.ip = lh.ip 

ORDER BY je.date DESC 

LIMIT 20, 20 ;
```

Comment: My approach ended up being different, +1 though, see my answer below for more details, thanks.